# Satellite Surface Temperature in Orbit

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, communication-satellite, temperature, thermodynamics

I am trying to calculate the satellite surface temperature in Orbit for Thermal Tests of our satellite.
Referring "Space Vehicle Design, D.Griffin, Ch.9, the equations of heat transfer on the surface of the satellite is -
[image: Space Vehicle Design, D.Griffin, Ch.9]

Resources say Albedo for Earth is 0.3 (average). Should we take albedo as constant or simulate it for the orbit.

How do I calculate the temperature of Earth (Te) at different time interval in the orbit?